# MVC - Git - Not fully merged index

Tags: asp.net-mvc, git, model-view-controller, entity-framework-6

I am using Visual Studio 2015 with Team Explorer using Git with one partner. I am employing the Code first method using MVC with Entity Framework 6.

When I am trying to Commit my changes, I get the following Error:

"An error occurred. Detailed message: Cannot create a tree from a not fully merged index."

From what I have read, the problem should have been that I had to launch git-bash.exe and type the command `git status`, so that I could get a list of what is wrong and `git add [filePath]` the file paths to fix it, and I did, but I unfortunately get the same error.

It was also suggested that I had to have all my changes included and make sure that none of them are excluded, which is the case.

If you need any more details, please let me know,
thank you.

Comment: What is the output of your `git status` in terminal ? You have described it but it's easier to infer from the output.

Comment: `On branch master

Initial commit

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git rm --cached <file>..." to unstage)
new file:     usr/share/.../...` followed by a few hundred green lines like this: `new file:        usr/share/.../...`